# Power Steering Failure on 2008 Ford Taurus

Tags: ford, power-steering, taurus

2008 Ford Taurus SE, 123K miles

**Symptoms**

1. Hard to turn – seems to be left of center (get to left of center,
   harder to turn left; hard to turn right until you break right of
   center).
2. No leaks
3. Minimal noise
4. Easy to turn if off the ground
5. Easier to turn if revved to 2000 RPM, but still difficult

**Possible Diagnosis**

Stuck Valve?

**Possible Fix?**

As an alternative to replacing the entire system, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjId3bfMBUQ) by Scotty Kilmer suggests using a product called Trans Tune to attempt to clean the internals of the system.  I don't know enough about this to know if this is a good idea, or if there are potential bad side effects (I don't want to destroy seals and the like, etc.)